# Acess data from json with arrays

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

I have json object from which I want to get data in connectionPoints which is array. It looks like this:

```
assetType : "this"

connectionPoints:Array(1)

type:{name: "Structure",
```

In TS file is something like this (entity is all this json object):

```
@Input() set elements(elements){

        this._elements = elements;

        if( elements && elements.length > 0){

            this.entity = elements[0];
        }else {

            this.entity = {};
        }
    }
```

And html:

```
<input type="text" value={{here i want to show connection.type}}/>
```

I want to acess data in connectionPoints array...position, system, type ... so that I can show that in html input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`ngModel`** as follows

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entity.connectionPoints[0].type"/>
```